# How to change a color of buttons concurrent MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

A have a problem. What I need: a red background can have only one button. For example I click first button, so two others button need to have darkgray color. If first button was clicked and have rad background, then I clicked second button, only the second button need to have red background, that is first and third buttons change background to darkred. My code:

xaml
<Page.Resources>

```
    <conv:ColorToSolidBrush x:Key="ConverterOfColors"/>
    <viewModels:VM1_2VM x:Key="D1"/>
</Page.Resources>



<WrapPanel Margin="200 0 0 0" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource D1}}">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource SquareButton}" Content="Basic" Margin="182 0 0 0" Background="{Binding BackgroundButton1, Converter={StaticResource ConverterOfColors}}"
              Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource SquareButton}" Margin="55 0 0 0" Content="Standard"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource SquareButton}" Margin="55 0 0 0" Content="Premium"/>
        </WrapPanel>
```

So here I bind a command to button, so when i clicked it background change.

Command:

```
public class MyCommandForPage: ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    private bool _canEx;

    public MyCommandForPage(Action ac, bool cE)
    {
        _action = ac;
        _canEx = cE;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canEx;

    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        
        _action();
    }

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Converter

```
public class ColorToSolidBrush: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (value is Color)
            return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported type [" + value.GetType().Name + "], ColorToSolidColorBrushValueConverter.Convert()");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
private System.Windows.Media.Color backgroundButton1 = Colors.DarkRed;
public System.Windows.Media.Color BackgroundButton1
    {
        get { return backgroundButton1; }
        set { backgroundButton1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundButton1));
        }
    }
public ICommand ClickCommand1
    {
        get
        {
            return clickCommand ?? (clickCommand = new MyCommandForPage(()=>ChangeBackColor(), true));
        }
    }
    public void ChangeBackColor()
    {
        backgroundButton1 = Colors.Red;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundButton1));
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to style a set of RadioButtons.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it only for 3 buttons, than it could be something like this:

```
    <WrapPanel Margin="200 0 0 0" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource D1}}">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource SquareButton}" Command="{Binding Path=ClickCommand1}" Content="Basic" Margin="182 0 0 0" Background="{Binding BackgroundButton1, Converter={StaticResource ConverterOfColorsConverters}}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource SquareButton}" Command="{Binding Path=ClickCommand2}"  Margin="55 0 0 0" Content="Standard" Background="{Binding BackgroundButton2, Converter={StaticResource ConverterOfColorsConverters}}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource SquareButton}" Command="{Binding Path=ClickCommand3}"  Margin="55 0 0 0" Content="Premium" Background="{Binding BackgroundButton3, Converter={StaticResource ConverterOfColorsConverters}}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
```

And in ViewModel something like this:

```
public partial class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public MainViewModel()
{
    BackgroundButton1 = Colors.DarkRed;
}

#region Notify

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
#endregion Notify

private Color backgroundButton1 { get; set; }
public Color BackgroundButton1
{
    get { return backgroundButton1; }
    set
    {
        backgroundButton1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundButton1));
    }
}

private Color backgroundButton2 { get; set; }
public Color BackgroundButton2
{
    get { return backgroundButton2; }
    set
    {
        backgroundButton2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundButton2));
    }
}

private Color backgroundButton3 { get; set; }
public Color BackgroundButton3
{
    get { return backgroundButton3; }
    set
    {
        backgroundButton3 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundButton3));
    }
}
public ICommand ClickCommand1
    => new MyCommandForPage(() => ChangeBackColor1(), true);

public ICommand ClickCommand2
    => new MyCommandForPage(() => ChangeBackColor2(), true);

public ICommand ClickCommand3
    => new MyCommandForPage(() => ChangeBackColor3(), true);

public void ChangeBackColor1()
{
    BackgroundButton1 = Colors.Red;
    BackgroundButton2 = Colors.DarkGray;
    BackgroundButton3 = Colors.DarkGray;
}

public void ChangeBackColor2()
{
    BackgroundButton1 = Colors.DarkRed;
    BackgroundButton2 = Colors.Red;
    BackgroundButton3 = Colors.DarkRed;
}

public void ChangeBackColor3()
{
    BackgroundButton1 = Colors.DarkGreen;
    BackgroundButton2 = Colors.DarkGreen;
    BackgroundButton3 = Colors.Red;
}
}
```